# Antd form value not received onFinish

Tags: reactjs, antd

I am developing an admin portal using Antd and this is something the I need in the design.

[image]

I managed to develop the design using the following code

```
<Form
labelWrap
wrapperCol={{ span: 24 }}
initialValues={detail && detail.object}
onFinish={handleEdit}>
<Row gutter={100}>
    <Col span={12}>
        <Item
            labelCol={{ span: 7 }}
            label='Status'
            name='status'
            valuePropName='checked'
            required>
            <Space> //-----------#1
                <p className='text-green'>Active</p> //--------#2
                <Switch defaultChecked={detail && detail.object.status} />
                <p className='text-red'>Inactive</p> //------------#3
            </Space> //---------#4
        </Item>
    </Col>
</Row>
</Form>
```

But when I try to handle the submit function, I am not getting the value of the switch element. I comes as `undefined`.

```
const handleEdit = async (values) => {
    console.log(values);
};
```

But I get the status value correctly when the `Switch` component is the immediate child of the `Item` by removing commented lines #1, #2, #3, #4.

I tried using the `form.getFieldsValue()` method. But that also didn't help.

Is there any way I can get the value in the desired way?

Comment: Switch Component should be the only child of the Item then you will get the correct value. But since you want to customize the switch component. You can follow these two examples. By following these examples, will solve your problem. [Example 1](https://ant.design/components/form#components-form-demo-complex-form-control), [Example 2](https://ant.design/components/form#formitemusestatus)

Comment: I followed the first example. I wrapped the `Switch` component inside `Item` and gave that one `name` and `valuePropName` attributes. Thank you so much. Please put your comment as an answer. So that I can upvote and mark as accepted answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pass `name` prop to `Form.Item`, the first child of `Form.Item` is controlled by `Form.Item`.
Since `Switch` is not the first child of `Form.Item`, it is not controlled by `Form.Item` and you didn't get the value `status`.
There are two possible solutions:

Solution 1: Use Form.Item with `noStyle` prop to design the layout (You can follow this example [Complex form control](https://ant.design/components/form#components-form-demo-complex-form-control))

Solution 2: Create a custom component that will receives `value` & `onChange` prop. [Example](https://ant.design/components/form#formitemusestatus)

```
import { Col, Form, Row, Space, Switch } from 'antd';

const { Item } = Form;

const CustomSwitch = ({ value, onChange }) => {
    return (
        <Space>
            <p className='text-green'>Active</p>
            <Switch value={value} onChange={onChange} />
            <p className='text-red'>Inactive</p>
        </Space>
    );
};

const App = () => {
    return (
        <Form labelWrap wrapperCol={{ span: 24 }}>
            <Row gutter={100}>
                <Col span={12}>
                    {/* Solution 1 */}
                    <Item labelCol={{ span: 7 }} label='Status'>
                        <Space>
                            <p className='text-green'>Active</p>
                            <Item name='status' noStyle valuePropName='checked' required>
                                <Switch />
                            </Item>
                            <p className='text-red'>Inactive</p>
                        </Space>
                    </Item>

                    {/* Solution 2 */}
                    <Item labelCol={{ span: 7 }} label='Status' name='status' valuePropName='checked' required>
                        <CustomSwitch />
                    </Item>
                </Col>
            </Row>
        </Form>
    );
};

export default App;
```